# Swift 4: PHAsset to Image reduces quality

Tags: swift, uiimage, data-conversion, phasset

I'm using a framework called OpalImagePicker, it allows me to pick several images instead of one. It returns an array of PHAssets.
I want to get these PHAssets, turn them into image, then convert them to base64 string so that i can send them to my data base.
But there's a problem: the images have really low quality when I try to get them from the PHAsset array.

Here's my code:

```
 let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
            requestOptions.version = .current
            requestOptions.deliveryMode = .opportunistic
            requestOptions.resizeMode = .exact
            requestOptions.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
            let imagePicker = OpalImagePickerController()
            imagePicker.maximumSelectionsAllowed = 4
            imagePicker.allowedMediaTypes = Set([PHAssetMediaType.image])
            self.presentOpalImagePickerController(imagePicker, animated: true,
                select: { (assets) in
                    for a in assets{
                       // print(a)
                       // self.img.append(a.image)
                       self.img.append(a.imagehd(targetSize: CGSize(width: a.pixelWidth, height: a.pixelHeight), contentMode: PHImageContentMode.aspectFill, options: requestOptions))
```

and the function:

```
func imagehd(targetSize: CGSize, contentMode: PHImageContentMode, options: PHImageRequestOptions?) -> UIImage {
           var thumbnail = UIImage()
           let imageManager = PHCachingImageManager()
           imageManager.requestImage(for: self, targetSize: targetSize, contentMode: contentMode, options: options, resultHandler: { image, _ in
               thumbnail = image!
           })
           return thumbnail
       }
```

I tried to give "request options.version" the ".original" value, or even high quality to delivery Mode, but then it just gives me nothing (image is nil)
I'm really lost. Can someone help?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: imageManager.requestImage is an asynchronous method. you can't wait an asynchronous method finish to return the thumbnail. What you need is to add a completion handler to your imagehd method.

Comment: Alright, I managed to find an alternative by using another delegate method from the API that automatically gives images instead of asset. I tried adding a completion handler but it didn't change anything, sadly. Thanks for answering tho, it might be a piece of the solution!

Comment: It didn't change anything is too vague. Please edit your question and post your code. `.opportunistic ` may call your completion handler more than once. **If the synchronous property is NO, Photos may call the resultHandler block (that you specified in the requestImageForAsset:targetSize:contentMode:options:resultHandler: method more than once. Photos may call your result handler once to provide a low-quality image suitable for displaying temporarily while it prepares a high-quality image.**

Comment: **If low-quality image data is immediately available, this first call may occur before the requestImageForAsset:targetSize:contentMode:options:resultHandler: method returns. When the high-quality image is ready, Photos calls your result handler again to provide it.
If the image manager has already cached the requested image, or if the synchronous property is YES, Photos calls your result handler only once.**

Comment: I see. Thanks for the detailed explaination. I'll try it out!

Comment: did you find any solution ?... I have the same problem